# How do I make Swiper autoplay after un-hiding container? (idangero.us/swiper)

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

### Main Issue

I am trying to use Swiper within a div that has it's visibility toggled. However, after hiding and showing the div, Swiper does not autoplay - even after triggering mySwiper.Update(), mySwiper.autoplay.start(), with observer and observeParents options set true.

#### Alternative Solution

Using new Swiper inside the toggle visibility function does work to make it autoplay, but it causes a new set of problems. Dragging doesn't work properly and the autoplay will jump around sporadically.

#### Code

I created two codepens to demonstrate:

- [Main (Update & Autoplay)](https://codepen.io/daltimus/pen/aboyGdE)
- [Alternative (Destroy & Re-create)](https://codepen.io/daltimus/pen/QWLMrGN)

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/css/swiper.min.css">
</head>

<style>
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.nav, .swiper-container {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
}
</style>

<body>
<div class="nav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggleHidden();">Toggle Hidden</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="startFunction();">Start Autoplay</a>
</div>

<!-- Swiper parent container -->
<div class="swiper-parent active">
    <!-- Slider main container -->
    <div class="swiper-container">
        <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <!-- Slides -->
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src='https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/08/19/07/45/pets-4415649_960_720.jpg' class="slide-image"/>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src='https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/07/02/08/10/sunny-4311828_960_720.jpg' class="slide-image"/>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src='https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/08/25/16/57/purple-4429887_960_720.jpg' class="slide-image"/>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src='https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/02/15/11/04/book-3998252_960_720.jpg' class="slide-image"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
//Swiper Initialization
new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    // Optional parameters
    observer: true,
    observeParents: true,
    loop: true,
    loopedSlides: 4,
    slidesPerView: 1,
    speed: 1800,
    autoplay: {
      delay: 100,
      disableOnInteraction: true,
    },
});

var mySwiper = document.querySelector('.swiper-container').swiper;

function startFunction(){
    mySwiper.autoplay.start();
};

function toggleHidden(){
  if ($('.swiper-parent').hasClass('active')){
    $('.swiper-parent').removeClass('active');
    $('.swiper-parent').addClass('hidden');
  } else {
    $('.swiper-parent').removeClass('hidden');
    $('.swiper-parent').addClass('active');
    mySwiper.update();
    mySwiper.autoplay.start();
  };
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Alternative toggle function:

```
function toggleHidden(){
  if ($('.swiper-parent').hasClass('active')){
    $('.swiper-parent').removeClass('active');
    $('.swiper-parent').addClass('hidden');
    mySwiper.destroy();
  } else {
    $('.swiper-parent').removeClass('hidden');
    $('.swiper-parent').addClass('active');
    new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        observer: true,
        observeParents: true,
        loop: true,
        loopedSlides: 4,
        slidesPerView: 1,
        speed: 1800,
        autoplay: {
          delay: 100,
          disableOnInteraction: true,
        },
    });
    var mySwiper = document.querySelector('.swiper-container').swiper;
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, though, I am inexperienced so I imagine it is not the best or cleanest way to accomplish this.

Here is the [codepen solution](https://codepen.io/daltimus/pen/zYOdayO)

I used this line `$("#swiper-parent-id").load(location.href+" #swiper-parent-id>*","");` to reload the div content, causing the instance of Swiper to be destroyed when hiding the div.

Then when showing the div, I created a new instance of Swiper.

This is what I intended to do with the alternative solution, but for some reason this worked, while `mySwiper.destroy();` did not work.

**EDIT:**
  Since I posted originally I have gotten mySwiper.destroy(); to work properly. If anyone else is having this problem, it was due to the way I was initializing swiper. It works best to do so in a document.ready function at the end of your body code.